# Spring Boot 2.0.0 Migration - JPA Repository save issue

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-5.x

I just migrated my app from Spring Boot 1.3.3 to 2.0.0.RELEASE and did most of the changes to get my project up and running.

However, I am facing an issue when I call ANY repository's save() option. The same structures and DO's were working perfectly fine in 1.3.3.

Whenever I go to save (in any repository), I get the following error:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement

Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'POLICY' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.
```

My PolicyDO's id is setup like this:

```
private @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO,generator="policyId_seq) @SequenceGenerator(name="policyId_seq",sequenceName="POLICYID_SEQ",allocationSize=1) Long id;
```

Here is a snapshot of my repository:

```
public interface PolicyRepository extends CrudRepository<PolicyDO, Long> { PolicyDO findByPolicyNum(String policyNum); PolicyDO findByProposalNum(String proposalNum); }
```

I've been googling for past 2 hours but cannot find a way to set IDENTITY_INSERT on via a configuration or annotation. Anyone can help with this? I've even tried setting all my IDs to null so it has to generate all of them before inserting, but still nothing

Comment: The Spring-Boot team highly recomment: 
_If you’re currently running with an earlier version of Spring Boot, we strongly recommend that you upgrade to Spring Boot 1.5 before migrating to Spring Boot 2.0._ [source](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Release-Notes)

Comment: Why are you using GenerationType.AUTO when you're passing a SequenceGenerator? I think strategy should be GenerationType.SEQUENCE

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem when I migrated to 2.0.0. After investigating the issue I realised the sequences in DB weren't working properly so I had to play around with the settings.

I don't know why but removing generator from @GeneratedValue annotation and changing strategy type to IDENTITY solved the problem.

In your case it would look like:

```
private @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY) @SequenceGenerator(name="policyId_seq",sequenceName="POLICYID_SEQ",allocationSize=1) Long id;
```

Comment: Ohh that resolved my issue. It's very strange behavior.